# How to add specific camera view using numbers to the script?

Tags: scripting, 3d-view, camera

I currently have this script, and I am trying to add an upper right view of my character to the scene but it's only looking at the feet of the character. Ideally, the upper right camera view would be above the current right camera angle, just that it's elevated and rotated downwards. I'm new to Blender, and just started using it this week, could someone help? I'm quite stuck on this.  The one I am trying to add is called "uppright". Thank you!!

```
import bpy
import math


def set_camera_view(view_type, LeftRight_adjust, Closeness_adjust, Height_adjust, Camera_angle):


    # Get the camera object
    camera = bpy.data.objects.get("Camera")
    #camera1 = bpy.data.objects.get("Camera.001")

    # Adjusting the camera axis to be the same as the movement
    camera.track_axis = 'POS_Y'
    camera.up_axis = 'Z'

    # Get the object
    target_object = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube")

    # Get the location of the target object
    target_location = target_object.location
    
    # Adjust the camera angles
    camera.data.angle = math.radians(Camera_angle)    
        
    # Define camera parameters based on view type
    if view_type.lower() == "front":
        rotation_angles_degrees = (90, 0, 180)
        camera.location = (target_location[0] - LeftRight_adjust, target_location[1] + Closeness_adjust, target_location[2] + Height_adjust)
    
    elif view_type.lower() == "right":
        rotation_angles_degrees = (90, 0, 270)
        camera.location = (target_location[0] - Closeness_adjust, target_location[1] - LeftRight_adjust, target_location[2] + Height_adjust)
        
    elif view_type.lower() == "back":
        rotation_angles_degrees = (90, 0, 360)
        camera.location = (target_location[0] + LeftRight_adjust, target_location[1] - Closeness_adjust, target_location[2] + Height_adjust)
                
    elif view_type.lower() == "left":
        rotation_angles_degrees = (90, 0, 90)
        camera.location = (target_location[0] + Closeness_adjust, target_location[1] + LeftRight_adjust, target_location[2] + Height_adjust)
    
    elif view_type.lower() == "uppright":
        rotation_angles_degrees = (70, 0, 81)
        camera.location = (target_location[0] - Closeness_adjust, target_location[1] - LeftRight_adjust, target_location[2] + Height_adjust)
    
    
    else:
        print("Invalid view type. Please choose 'front', 'right', 'back', or 'left'.")
        return
    
    # Set the rotation of the camera
    camera.rotation_euler = [math.radians(angle) for angle in rotation_angles_degrees]




# Default
LeftRight_adjust = 0
#zoom out function is closeness adjust 
Closeness_adjust = 5
Height_adjust = 1
Camera_angle = 60

set_camera_view("uppright", LeftRight_adjust, Closeness_adjust, Height_adjust, Camera_angle)
```

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to Blender! If you want someone to *be able* to help you, you should provide a complete working demo script and a few words about the required setup. What is needed? What do you expect? What doesn't work? There are several issues here: The indent of your script is wrong, the import statements are missing, the *export_video* function is irrelevant, there must be a target object named "0000", and there are 2 cameras used in different cases...?! Anyone who wants to help you must fix these things first. Why not change the script so it works with the default cube and camera?

Comment: I've changed the script so it works now with the default camera and cube. The result of the script is that the camera points to the "feet" of the cube. But it is also facing away from the cube. This is probably because your *camera1* and the "character" have different positions than *camera* and the default cube. -- Just wondering, are you sure you need this script? If you want to make the camera point at something you can use a *Damped Track* constraint and an *Empty* as target.